# AWS S3 - Getting 400 error when trying to access from aws web console; Also getting lots of errors in devtools at AWS home

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

just noticed this and am worried. Looking for advice on the cause and possible solutions.

- S3 does not open on either sub-admin or root account. Getting 400 error.

  - haven't noticed any other resources that aren't loading.. I can access lambda, ddb, apigateway, etc. just fine.
- Not sure if it's related but I noticed a bunch of errors in dev tools console when I sign into AWS. Not sure if those are normal as I've never taken notice before.. but thought it might be worth including.

Included screenshots of both below.

[400 Error when attempting to access S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGGJ.png)

[Errors in devtools at AWS home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfrsH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the request your submitting has a header which is too large.
Have you tried using a different browser?

If that works you may just need to clear the cache in the current.
Assuming it still happens let us know what you tried.

The error 413 means Request entity too large.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.  I'm self-taught with lots to learn. Do you mind helping me understand what was going on here? No need for an essay, just a few sentences if you have the time. I'd appreciate it. In any case, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hey, I'm also self-taught for the most part so I totally understand. I know it's a bit late but basically I would say it probably has to do with code that keeps running and stays cached and until that cache gets reloaded it was stuck. Any bad code can cause an excess pileup of data that has no use or value so probably not user error in any case!